# If an atom loses electron, it becomes a cation; it does not form a hole. However, when electron is lost from a bond, it forms a hole and not a cation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, semiconductor-physics, electronics, electronic-band-theory

If an atom loses an electron, it becomes a cation, and when an electron is lost from a bond, it forms a hole. This is what the professor told the class, but I am not able to find the reason for that being the rule.

While writing this question, I came up with a somewhat satisfactory reason for electron loss from a bond creating a hole instead of a cation. In a bond, the electron is being shared between the two atoms and does not belong to a single atom. Therefore, we can neither give +e to a single atom nor +e/2 to each because e is the smallest charge possible. Am I thinking in the right direction?

Comment: yes, that is the reason for "inventing" holes.

Comment: I apologize, but I'm having difficulty discerning whether your statement is expressed with sarcasm or if you are confirming it. Could you kindly provide clarification?

Comment: Isn't a hole a concept from solid-state physics rather than chemistry of molecules? It makes sense in solid-state systems because the lack of an electron in an almost-filled band behaves like a quasiparticle opposite to an electron in an almost-empty band: e.g. contributes to conductivity, interacts with an electron making up an exciton etc.

Comment: You also need to remember, that ion is negatively charged. But in a semiconductor is electrically neutral (when there's a hole in the valence band, there's also a compensating electron in the conduction band). You can push ions around using electric field, but even a heavily p-doped silicon wafer won't move if you try to push it with this way.  

Perhaps reading the answers to the question below will give you more overview:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/172891/how-is-a-semiconductor-electrically-neutral

Comment: @Logan  I was not being sarcastic. It starts by the observation that electrons are shared, and then different quantum mechanical models develop to study the specific cases.

Comment: Thanks everyone i got the concept!

Comment: Loosing electron from a bond does not necessarily mean that some of involved atoms get's ionized. Imagine pair of atoms shares electron in a bond in $1s$  orbital. Now one atom get's energy packet and it's electron in a bond jumps to $2s$ orbital, thus leaving the hole in the bond between atoms. But none of atoms lost their electrons, just configuration changed.